# Plotting discontinuous functions

Tags: plotting, piecewise

I want to plot the two roots of a polynomial function. At some value of the variable x, they "swap" and the lines change. However, I want each branch to have te same line style. Is it possible to solve this without using "piecewise"?

[image]

Comment: "I want each branch to have the same line style" so like in the picture? Or you want both branches to have the same line style? What have you tried?

Comment: Please include more information, with code (nicely formatted in code blocks). Edit your post to include these. Good information to have would be: the polynomial, what you've tried to compute the roots, what you've tried to plot them, etc.  This will give us a much better idea of what you're trying to do, where you are the in problem, and what your level of *Mathematica* expertise is. Then we can help!

Comment: Hi vnzk, welcome to M.SE. It's usually helpful to have a concrete example of your problematic code -- that should result in better answers.

Comment: I want each branch to have a different line style. I will edit the post soon, so you guys can see what I did.